# PrimeFaces AutoComplete suggestions item is not selectable on Mouse Click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

I am trying to develop AutoComplete using Primeface p:autoComplete tag. Suggestion list value is selectable and set to textbox on enter key hit but the problem is if i hover on item and press mouse click then list item value is not set to textbox. Here is the snippet

```
<p:autoComplete
    value="#{autoComplete.city}"
    completeMethod="#{autoComplete.getCityList}"
    tabindex="1" id="city" placeholder="Mumbai" appendTo="@this"
    queryDelay="100">
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: If `city` is not `String` or primitive you need a converter. There are many [examples](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) on PrimeFaces showcase.

Comment: Also could be that there is not submit. You can add a `p:commandButton` to submit the form on a button click, or `p:ajax event="itemSelect"` to submit immediately on select.

Comment: @Geinmachi city is string only

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov Actually it has already submit button but i didn't put submit button code in snippet but main problem is **using key up and down** focus will come on item and after **hitting a Enter** value is set to inputtextfield but if you use mouse click to select item it won't set to inputtextfield instead of suggestion list is hide. And as you suggested `p:ajax event="itemSelect"` listener is called on Enter key hit but it isn't called on mouse select event, Item list is hidden.